# Fire event from Commands to Taskpane in Office Web Addin

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am developing an Office/Excel Web addin using React in which I have some Ribbon/ContextMenu button which needs to update data in Taskpane UI. Previously I was using Storage event and it was working fine. However recently I moved to [Shared JS Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) which stopped Storage event as now Commands and Taskpane both work under same Page so definitely Storage event will not fire as per definition.
I am struggling to find out any possible solution/event in Shared Js Runtime to fire an event from commands.js to Taskpane/Component/App.js file.
Please suggest

Comment: Please explain why you need an event. If you are using a shared runtime, then the ribbon button and the task pane share the same global namespace, don't they? So, the button can just update a global data object.

Comment: Thank you for response @RickKirkham. Let's assume I have three Radio buttons in Taskpane page and three buttons in Ribbon. When user click on Ribbon button, I need to check respective Radio button in Taskpane.

Comment: Might be I am over-looking something as newbie in this domain. My "command.js" where Ribbon button event handler is a simple Javascript file whereas App.js is React Component class where I have Radio buttons.

Comment: Try this: Have the ribbon button set handler set a global variable. Set up an observer pattern in the task pane that checks that variable every 10th of a second to see if it's value has changed since the last time it was checked. If it has changed, use the new value of the global variable to change the state of the React component.

Comment: Dear @RickKirkham , What I understand from your comments. I exported "getGlobal" function in Commands.js file like this:
`export function getGlobal() {
  return typeof self !== "undefined"
    ? self
    : typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? window
    : typeof global !== "undefined"
    ? global
    : undefined;
}`
and then imported it into App.js file
`import { getGlobal } from '../../commands/commands'`

But it is not compiling and giving error at build time
_ERROR in ./src/commands/commands.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token_

Comment: ERROR in ./src/commands/commands.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT License. -->
|
| <!DOCTYPE html>
 @ ./src/taskpane/components/App.js 198:0-52 631:31-40 636:26-35
 @ ./src/taskpane/index.js
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch ./src/taskpane/index.js

ERROR in chunk taskpane [entry]
taskpane.js

Comment: @RickKirkham can you please share some code what you are suggesting?

Comment: Anyone please????

Comment: See this sample: [Share global data with a shared runtime](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-global-state).

Comment: I have following loader defined in Webpack.config.js which seems different than your solution repository:
`rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          use: [
            'react-hot-loader/webpack',
            'babel-loader',
            {
              loader: "babel-loader", 
              options: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },`

This might causing loader error I mentioned above???

Comment: Since your add-in has a command.HTML file, I think **MAYBE** you will need to call the html-loader inside the `rules` section of the webpack config. This is what it looks like in our sample: ```{
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader"
        },``` But the webpack issue is different from your original problem and it should be a new question on Stack, tagged with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

The following github repo illustrates one way of updating the task pane when you press a ribbon button.
https://github.com/OfficeAddins/sharedruntime

[image]

Comment: Its not clear yet. In this add-in we have single JS file but eventually professional application will have separate files for Functions/Commands/Taskpane so would be better if we access it using separate files in real world scenario.

Comment: This does not seem to work for Word at all....the add-in does not load

Comment: Hi,  I have this same scenario, did you find any solution? I have stuck here and it is becoming frustrating for me. @user1455675

Comment: This particular example will only work in Excel. This is controlled by the manifest file:
<Host xsi:type = "Workbook">

If you need the sample to work in Word, you will need to change the host to "Document"